# Morphisms of rings that define morphisms of derivations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebras

I am not super experienced in (commutative) algebra and in the course of some of my work I noticed that I had a need for morphisms of rings that are compatible with the asssociated module of derivations. Let me set some notation.

$ R $ and $ S $ are rings and and $ \phi \colon R \to S $ is a ring homomorphism. Let $ Der(R) $ and $Der(S)$ denote the respective modules of derivations. Since $ S $ is an $ R $-module, we can also define $ Der(R, S ) $ to be the $R$-module of derivations on $R$ with values in $S$.

Notice that there are natural $R$-module homomorphisms $ Der(R) \to Der(R,S) $ and $ Der(S) \to Der(R,S) $ by post- and pre-composition by $\phi$, respectively. There is also a natural $S$-module homomorphism $S \otimes_R Der(R) \to Der(R,S)$.

Now let me propose two definitions. My hope is that these definitions exist in the literature and I am just too ignorant to know the actual terminology.

**Definition 1**: We say that $\phi$ is of the *first kind* if there exists a unique morphism of $R$-modules $\alpha \colon Der(R) \to Der(S) $ which makes the following diagram commute:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
Der(R) & \rightarrow & Der(S) \\
 & \searrow & \downarrow \\
 & & Der(R,S)
\end{array}
$$
**Motivating Example**: Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $U$ is an open subset. The restriction map $C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(U)$ is a ring homomorphism of the first kind. I suspect this is actually true for any locally ringed space (?).

**Definition 2**: We say that $\phi$ is of the *second kind* if there exists a unique morphism of $S$-modules $\beta \colon Der(S) \to S \otimes_R Der(R) $ which makes the following diagram commute:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
Der(S) & \rightarrow & S \otimes_R Der(R) \\
 & \searrow & \downarrow \\
 & & Der(R,S)
\end{array}
$$
**Motivating Example**: Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth compact manifolds and $f \colon M \to N $ is a smooth function. The pull-back map $f^* \colon C^\infty(N) \to C^\infty(M) $ is of the second kind.

With the definitions out of the way, let me ask my questions.

**Question 1**: Is there a nice category of rings where every homomorphism is of the first and/or second kind?

**Question 2**: Are the uniqueness conditions in the definitions necessary? In my fumbling efforts I have not been able to find counter-examples. (**I have since partially answered this, see edit**)

**Question 3**: Are morphisms of local rings always of the second kind?

**Question 4**: If I assume that $Der(R)$ and $Der(S)$ are projective and finitely generated modules does that imply that $\phi$ is of the second kind?

**Question 5**: When is a morphism of local rings of the first/second kind? In the algebraic geometry universe, which morphisms of schemes induce homomorphisms of the first/second kind?

**EDIT 1**: Regarding uniqueness I see that there are plenty of examples that fail uniqueness. For instance, if one takes $M$ to be a manifold and $\pi \colon M \times M \to M $ to be projection to the first factor, one can show that there are actually many module homomorphisms $ \mathcal{X}(M \times M) \to \mathcal{X} (M)$ which make the 'first kind' diagram commute. However, none of them are natural/canonical.

**EDIT 2**: I figured I should include the version in terms of Kahler forms. Let's assume that $R$ and $S$ are $k$-algebras for some fixed field $k$. We denote by $\Omega_R$ and $\Omega_S$ the usual modules of Kahler forms.

The universal property of the Kahler differential tells us that
$$ Der(R) \cong Hom_R(\Omega_R,R) \quad Der(S) \cong Hom(\Omega_S,S) \quad Der(R,S) \cong Hom_R(\Omega_R, S) $$

One can use these isomorphisms to substitute these objects into the above diagrams.

The one glimmer of hope is that there is actually a natural homomorphism $\phi_* \colon \Omega_R \to \Omega_S$ obtained by the rule $ \phi_*(dr) = d(\phi(r))$. Still, this is not enough to get the maps. From this point of view, it seems likely that if one assumes that $\Omega_R$ and $\Omega_S$ are sufficiently nice modules, then $\phi$ will be of the first/second kind. It seems like it could also be related to the structure of $S$ as an $R$-module. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to show that these conditions suffice. I also have no intuition as to which sorts of rings will have projective/finitely generated/etc modules of Kahler forms.

Comment: **Why the examples are true**: Derivations of smooth functions on a manifold are the same as vector fields. In the example of the first kind, the function $\alpha$ is just the restriction of a global vector field to an open subset. The diagram commutes because it doesn't matter whether you apply the vector field before or after restricting.

For the second kind example, one can identify $ C^\infty(M) \otimes_{C^\infty(N)} \Gamma(TN) $ with sections of $ f^* TN $. The map $\Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(f^*TN)$ just comes from the differential.

Comment: Just a general remark: many results on derivations can be equivalently stated in terms of differentials using [Lemma 10.130.1 here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RM). So maybe your definitions exist in the literature phrased in this language.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your comment. Per your remark I am able to rephrase these questions in terms of the Kahler differentials, as you said. Unfortunately, I haven't managed to use that to answer my questions.